# What does gekackt mean in this context (german slang)?

Tags: translation, german-to-english, slang

You guys are my peepz to go when it comes to proper ghetto german slang. I can’t figure out the meaning of a line in hiphop song lyrics. What’s the loose translation of:

> *Ganz, ehrlich, hätt'st du gekackt, wär' besser!*

My take on it is:

> *Yeah, true, you fucked it up, could’ve been better!*

Comment: Who is the artist and what's the name of the song?

Comment: It is Ali Bumaye - Skit (Rumble in the Jungle)

Comment: Lyrics: https://genius.com/Ali-bumaye-skit-rumble-in-the-jungle-lyrics

Comment: *Would have been better*, not *could*.

Comment: @userunknown *would have been better* requires a condition, so in his translation, *could* is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did google these "lyrics" and my interpretation of this line is:

> Had you taken a dump before, your rap would have been less sh*tty.

Answer (score 4):

The translation to english is just straight-forward: "Would you have been shitting, it (the result) would have been better." So your translation slightly misses the point, even if it is still in the right direction.